# Its/It's for "It", but not for other words?

Tags: orthography

Why is there a distinction between "it's" and "its"?

You can write "The cat's walking." where "cat's" might ambiguously be either "cat is" or "cat (possessive)", and I don't think anyone considers this to be a major problem of usage. What's different with its/it's?

Perhaps it is better to compare with other pronouns.

Its is substantially different in form than other genitive pronouns, in that it appears to be a relatively modern construction (OED has the earliest attested use in the 15th century) which in fact generalizes from the apostrophe possessive, or is a result of the same transformation that produced the apostrophe from OE strong|singular|masc./neut. -es. "Him"->"his" definitely isn't generalized from a widely attested grammatical rule; they've been in the language from old english essentially unchanged. By the logic that "its" operates similarly to other pronouns one would expect its (its' ?) modern form to be something like "his" which was its' original genitive form.

So my question is, who decided that its doesn't get an apostrophe, and why?

Comment: You should be looking at other pronouns rather than nouns. *His* vs. *he's*, *her* vs. *she's*, *their* vs. *they're* and so on and so forth — *its* vs. *it's* is the norm, not the exception.

Comment: Thank you for the update, though the question is a duplicate now. (Alas, I don't think we ever found a *truly satisfying* answer to the original, but if anyone can provide new insight, they're welcome to do it there.)

Comment: @colinro - Is "It is substantially different in form..." a quote/paraphrase from somewhere? Can you give the source please?

Comment: @nxx no, that was a claim of my own making, based on the etymological fact from my post and the similarity between it and its which is not present between him -> his. Although yes between her -> hers, so that is...factor

Comment: @RegDwigнt can you link to the original discussion?

Comment: The link is at the very top of this question. In the blue field. (And there are older questions still linked in turn from that one.)